# Upload an image using a URL in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload

I went through the tutorial to upload an image in Codeigniter with the Upload library, but I was wondering: Is it possible to upload an image using a URL in Codeigniter?

Comment: What does this mean exactly to "upload an image using a URL"? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Wesley Murch: See http://imageshack.us/ -- it's probably like that, where the user has the option to upload a file from their computer or link / retrieve an existing one from a site.

Comment: @stealthyninja: yes its like that. is it possible in codeigniter using the existing library?

Comment: @wesley murch: similar to what stealhyninja mentioned..

Comment: @Aby: See the links in my answer below -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185845/upload-an-image-using-a-url-in-codeigniter/7186033#7186033 -- you could use the Curl library to download a remote image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. See the answer on this question:  [Saving image from PHP URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/save-image-from-php-url-using-php).
If you're going to go the cURL route, see the CodeIgniter wiki entry: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Curl_library/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question clearly;

I think ***Upload a file using URL*** isn't a properties of Codeigniter or any other technologies. It's about operating system.

For example, you have a upload system with generated by PHP and Codeigniter. When you click ***Browse*** button, you can select an image in your computer or you can write an image link hosted on the internet. When you insert an image link, operating system generate a temporary path source (with your image) in your computer. In Windows, this could be `C:/Temp` folder. Then you can upload your image which you insert its' link.

[File Uploading Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Note: My english is off. Sorry for that.