# Save image to server from a URL

Tags: php, image, url, replace

I've built a mini-content management system with [CKEditor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor). The user has the ability to paste an image [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) from another website. Is there a way to to get all image URLs when the user submits the content, save all these images to the server, and replace another server's URL with URL of my server?

For example, the user wrote something like this:

```
<img src="somews.com/img1.jpg"/>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. ...
```

During the submit process [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) would save the image from `somews.com/img1.jpg` to the server, converts its URL to `myserver.com/photos/img1.jpg` and replaces  `<img src="somews.com/img1.jpg"/>` with  .. Is that possible?

Comment: Parse the submitted HTML, extract image URLs, download the images, store them, update the image URLs in the HTML. Done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php), [save image from php url using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/save-image-from-php-url-using-php)

Comment: it's simple for you. but how to do that?

Comment: I added you some duplicate questions, you should use the search before posting a new, combined question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have PHP5 and the HTTP stream wrapper enabled on your server, it's incredibly simple to copy it to a local file:

copy('http://somedomain.com/file.jpeg', '/tmp/file.jpeg');

This will take care of any pipelining etc. that's needed. If you need to provide some HTTP parameters there is a third 'stream context' parameter you can provide.

Comment: how to parse html for all image urls, do this, and convert results all urls

Comment: check here to parse html for image url
http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/parse-html-with-preg_match_all/