# Uncompress gzip compressed http response

Tags: php

I'm using php's `file_get_contents()` function to do a HTTP request. To save bandwidth I decided to add the `"Accept-Encoding: gzip"` header using `stream_context_create()`.

Obviously, `file_get_contents()` outputs a gzip encoded string so I'm using `gzuncompress()` to decode the encoded string but I get an error with data passed as argument.

```
[...] PHP Warning: gzuncompress(): data error in /path/to/phpscript.php on line 26
```

I know there is another function able to decompress gzipped data `gzdecode()` but it isn't included in my PHP version (maybe it is only available on SVN).

I know that cUrl decodes gzip stream on the fly (without any problem) but someone suggested me to use `file_get_contents()` instead of cUrl.

Do you know any other way to decompress gzipped data in PHP or why `gzuncompress()` outputs a Warning? It is absurd that `gzuncompress()` doesn't work as expected.

Notes:
The problem is certainly about PHP: the HTTP request is made to Tumblr API that give a well-encoded response.

Comment: Do you know why they suggested to use `file_get_contents` instead of cUrl?

Comment: No, I don't know, they said "it's better". I can go back to cUrl but I'm anyway curious about gzuncompress() issue.

Comment: Is it because the data is base64 encoded too?

Comment: Are you sure `file_get_contents` isn't doing the decompression for you? It's a long shot, I know... Try dumping the contents of the file and checking for the gzip magic number `0x1f8b` at the start of the file.

Comment: No, even added base64_decode() I get the same error.

Comment: Just to confirm, can you please include your code in the question - im doing this very thing and see no problems

Comment: Jonathan, printing out directly from file_get_contents() I get unreadable binary data, something like this: �Ž{�F�&�W���,A��]�x��X�o��x2��ӂ`��0.�

Comment: sorry sorry sorry... I didn't convert binary data to hex. Effectively the string starts with 1f8b08... so, what to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`gzuncompress`](http://php.net/gzuncompress) won't work for the `gzip` encoding. It's the decompression function for the `.Z` archives.

The manual lists a few workarounds for the missing [`gzdecode()`#82930](http://php.net/gzdecode#82930), or just use the one from [`upgradephp`](http://include-once.org/p/upgradephp/), or the gzopen temp file workaround.

Another option would be forcing the `deflate` encoding  with the `Accept-Encoding:` header and then using [`gzinflate()`](http://php.net/gzinflate) for decompression.

Comment: I'm developing an open source library so I can't force users to install upgradephp. The library installation should be as simple as possible so I'm turning to use cUrl that has built-in gzip support.

Comment: Uhm, what? You could just copy and paste that single function implementation out, if you don't want to ship the whole upgradephp snippet along.

Comment: Mario, thanks for your suggestion but I've just turned to cUrl leaving file_get_contents() implementation. Are you sure that importing gzdecode() from upgradephp will work withouth any other dependency?

Comment: Using upgrade.php worked.  Like a javascript shim for HTML5.  Perfect!  Thanks.

Comment: That upgradephp project is awesome. I added a Github clone for it: https://github.com/Polycademy/upgradephp

Answer (score 34):

Found this working for me: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php#106397

Optionally try: http://digitalpbk.com/php/file_get_contents-garbled-gzip-encoding-website-scraping

```
if ( ! function_exists('gzdecode'))
{
    /**
     * Decode gz coded data
     * 
     * http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php
     * 
     * Alternative: http://digitalpbk.com/php/file_get_contents-garbled-gzip-encoding-website-scraping
     * 
     * @param string $data gzencoded data
     * @return string inflated data
     */
    function gzdecode($data) 
    {
        // strip header and footer and inflate

        return gzinflate(substr($data, 10, -8));
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, i've been searching all over for this

Comment: It seems that gzinflate is not as flexible as gzdecode. example that works with gzdecode, but not with gzinflate: http://cdn.misterwhat.com/mwuk.min.gz.css?ver=3.1

Comment: Yes, this works. It should be the accepted answe for me

Answer (score 1):

Before decomress data you need to assemble it.
So if header contains

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

you need to unchank it.

```
function http_unchunk($data) {
    $res=[];
    $p=0; $n=strlen($data);
    while($p<$n) {
        if (preg_match("/^([0-9A-Fa-f]+)\r\n/",substr($data,$p,18),$m)) {
            $sz=hexdec($m[1]); $p+=strlen($m[0]);
            $res[]=substr($data,$p,$sz); $p+=$sz+2;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return implode('',$res);
}
```

if Content-Encoding is gzip or x-gzip or x-compress use gzdecode
if Content-Encoding is deflate use gzdeflate

```
...
if ($chunked) $body=http_unchunk($body);
if ($gzip) $body=gzdecode($body);
if ($deflate) $body=gzdeflate($body);
...
```