# PHP: Call to undefined function gzdecode()

Tags: php, function, undefined

I am getting a strange error message with the following piece of PHP code (I am not a PHP expert):

```
if ( $file_loc != NULL ) {
    if ( file_exists($file_loc) ) {
        printf(" file exists");
        $handle = fopen($file_loc, "rb");
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($file_loc));
        fclose($handle);
        $result = gzdecode($contents);
    }
}
```

I am basically trying to load text content from a gzipped file. I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function gzdecode() in ...\sites\MyScripts\fw2.php on line 80
```

Yet, when I take a look at [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php), it does not seem like I would need to include an extra library, or am I being wrong? How can I solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

Following another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802498/php-how-to-check-whether-a-library-has-been-properly-installed-and-enabled) to check whether this library is installed on my PC, the answer is yes, it is.

From PHP info:

[image]

So this is getting more and more confusing...

**UPDATE II**

I have tried:

```
<?php

echo phpversion().", ";

if (function_exists("gzdecode")) {
  echo "gzdecode OK, ";
} else {
  echo "gzdecode no OK, ";
}

if (extension_loaded('zlib')) {
  echo "zlib extension loaded ";
} else {
  echo "zlib extension not loaded ";
}

?>
```

and I get:

```
5.2.17, gzdecode no OK, zlib extension loaded
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. *"Zlib support in PHP is not enabled by default."* but *"The Windows version of PHP has built-in support for this extension. You do not need to load any additional extensions in order to use these functions."* Not 100% certain what exactly this means. Are you on Windows or *NIX?

Comment: I am on Windows 7 using an Acquia Dev Desktop installation.

Comment: Hm, that *is* interesting. How did you install PHP?

Comment: In fact, I am learning Drupal using a package available here: http://www.acquia.com/products-services/dev-desktop. This package installed PHP with Apache and MySQL. This installation is stable, but may be it did not install ZLib.

Comment: Can you try installing PHP separately?

Comment: @Waynn Before trying that, I want to check whether this is a simple installation issue. I have created another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802498/php-how-to-check-whether-a-libray-has-been-properly-installed-and-enabled

Comment: I can confirm that PHP 5.4.27 downloaded from windows.php.net doesn't support this function even it has to (because version is > 5.4.0 and zlib is built-in). PHP 5.4.27 on windows 7 behaves against PHP official documentation, so it looks like this is bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not always installed. From [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.installation.php):

> Zlib support in PHP is not enabled by default. You will need to configure PHP --with-zlib[=DIR]
>
> The Windows version of PHP has built-in support for this extension. You do not need to load any additional extensions in order to use these functions.

edit: Since this is the accepted answer still, I edited it to add the function suggested as replacement.

```
function gzdecode($data) { 
   return gzinflate(substr($data,10,-8)); 
}
```

Comment: The library is loaded, but the function does not exist. See my second update on my question.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=22123 implies that `gzdecode` only exists in PHP 6.

Comment: @WaynnLue A 10 year old bug report, with a 6 year old comment about PHP6 is not a good reference.

Comment: @Leigh Any suggestions for a better reference to post? :)

Comment: As you probably know, the PHP6 project from 6 years ago, is dead. The gzdecode function was finally [added to the codebase on 31st May 2010](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/11d24c1593d6617f73d3f290617bd8994182f4dc/ext/zlib/zlib.c#L711)  (you still need --with-zlib so your answer remains correct)

Answer (score 18):

gzdecode is not available unless PHP is complied with zlib. It will possibly be included in PHP 6, according to some sources. Notice in the manual how nearly all functions have given a PHP version number when it became / is available. Oddly, they don't think it needed to display a warning message.

Try this code (works for me) for gzdecode without checksums:

```
function gzdecode($data) 
{ 
   return gzinflate(substr($data,10,-8)); 
}
```

Comment: -1 for being factually incorrect. The manual isn't always 100% accurate, and this function certainly **is** available right now in PHP5. The feature set of PHP6 is far from decided, so your declaration that this function is slated for the next major version is nothing but assumption.

Comment: and you can prove this how?

Comment: It was not in my "PHP5" neither that of any of these other posters!

Comment: What exactly do I need to prove? I can prove the manual isn't accurate by the fact that it omits version information on a zlib function (as you can see), I can prove the feature set of PHP6 isn't decided because I follow the relevant mailing lists, and can assure you there is no talk of concrete features yet, and I can prove the function is in PHP5 [by linking you to the commit that it was introduced in, nearly 3 years ago](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/11d24c1593d6617f73d3f290617bd8994182f4dc/ext/zlib/zlib.c#L711) - Just because it's not on by default, doesn't mean it's not there.

Comment: 1) Don't use an old version of PHP, 2) Compile it with `--with-zlib`

Answer (score 0):

Function gzdecode is available since php 5.4[image]

My favorite solution is

[Uncompress gzip compressed http response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895852/uncompress-gzip-compressed-http-response)