# PHP: How to check whether a library has been properly installed and enabled?

Tags: php, installation

Following another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801908/php-call-to-undefined-function-gzdecode#comment12482721_9801908) on SO (I am no PHP expert), I am wondering whether the Zlib library has been properly installed on my local laptop. Documentation says there should be no need to manually install this library, but code using this library does not work.

[Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.installation.php) mentions a need to configure PHP `--with-zlib[=DIR]`, but for versions below 4.3. I am on 5.2.17. I have checked `php.ini`, but I see no reference to it. My PHP system has been installed with [Acquia Dev Desktop](http://www.acquia.com/products-services/dev-desktop).

How can I check whether the Zlib library has been properly installed and enabled on my local PC? Where should I take a look at? What should I look for? Thanks.

Comment: I would actually imagine that the fact that the function doesn't work mean that it's not properly installed, though I'm curious if there are other answers. :)

Comment: ZLib is installed on my PC, so back to the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use phpinfo() to get full information about libraries

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

or in your PHP code test for a given function

```
if (function_exists("gzcompress")) {
  echo "OK";
} else {
  die("zlib missing");
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Unless I'm missing something:

```
var_dump(function_exists('gzclose')); // or any gz-related functions
```

Or to be more specific and correct

```
if(extension_loaded('zlib'))
```

http://sg.php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php

Comment: The extension_loaded function is a more 'correct' answer to this question than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that, if you are using DevDesktop, you are referencing the Application/Devdesktop/php# version of PHP(links within DD prefs) (my dev machine has three: Mac OS, HomeBrew, and Acquia DevD)..

I used Homebrew to tap that ^ keg and install the plugin (Mac).