# Changing user-agent in DOM

Tags: php, dom

Hi i am trying to scrape some data on amazon but i always get blank result, i tried to change my useragent but it still does not work, please can someone look at what is wrong

```
<?php

require_once "core.php"; 

include "simple_html_dom.php";


$_curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3');
curl_setopt($_curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.amazon.com/Apple-iPhone-Plus-Unlocked-32GB/dp/B01N6ZAR0D/');
$html = curl_exec( $_curl );

$_htmlDom = new simple_html_dom();
$_htmlDom->load(  $html  );

echo $html;

}

?>
```

Comment: "does not work" is not a helpful problem statement.  _In what way_ does it not work?  What _does_ happen?  What do you expect to happen?  What debugging have you done?

Comment: i am trying to request amazon product page using php dom  but i am getting this screen shots link  : https://prnt.sc/nj7gkz , but if i change the link to aliexpress or ebay it loads fine

Comment: Do not switch `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` off.

Comment: @Dharman still does not work

Comment: Have you got an up to date cert? What does [`curl_error()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3987037/1839439) tell you?

Comment: @Dharman i am not getting any error, page load with weird text here is screenshot : https://prnt.sc/nj7gkz  and if i change link to aliexpress or ebay it loads fine.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53364974/getting-garbage-output-when-scraping-a-webpage-in-php