# json_decode and StackExchange api

Tags: php, symfony, stackexchange-api

I'm trying to use the [V2.2 of StackExchange api](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) with **PHP**. I'm using the **Symfony** project with Kriswallsmith's **buzz** library.

The problem comes when I try to print the content of response of HTTP request and its encode. I have already read lots of question related with this problem in StackOverflow but the problem still exists.

This is a portion of code where I show the problem:

```
echo "The url: ";
var_dump($url);
var_dump($response);
$content = $response->getContent();
echo "Json decode's content: ";
var_dump(json_decode($content, true));
echo "The error is";
switch(json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
        break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
        break;
    case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
        echo ' - Invalid or malformed JSON';
        break;
    case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
        echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
        break;
}

die();
```

This returns the following:

[image]

If you paste the

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers?site=stackoverflow&sort=activity&
```

in the browser, it returns a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurs to me that for some reason the content is not ungzipped:

```
$ curl https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers
�VJ-*�/��LQ�210ЁrsS���S����3KR2��R
                                  K3�RS�`J�sA�I�)��E@NIj�R-g��PP

$ curl https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers | gzip -d
{"error_id":400,"error_message":"site is required","error_name":"bad_parameter"}
```

You should be able to use PHP's [`gzuncompress`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php) function or dig Buzz a bit.

Comment: This is the reason but with `gzuncompress` function was still falling. This is the correct method/answer for my question. Thanks ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/10105319/2359967

Comment: @benatespina, well, actually an HTTP client should work out such technical things by itself: it can read the headers, can't it?