# Gzip between JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, post, gzip

I've managed to gzip my response from my server to my client, but now I also want to gzip the data send from the client to the server. I'm using [zlib.js](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js) as follows:

```
var gzip = new Zlib.Gzip(dataUint8Array);
var compressed = gzip.compress();
```

Where the returned compressed is a Uint8 array. How do I send the data to the server, especially, how do I decode this in PHP? I tried using gzdecode in PHP to decode the array, but that didn't work. Then I tried to convert the compressed array in JS back to a string before sending it to the server, but gzdecode could also not decode that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this answer will help.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8896524/3585500

Force uncompression with the Accept-Encoding: deflate header.

Comment: Looked at that and played around, but can't get it to work. Should I send a byte array or string to the server for this?

Comment: If you're posting it back via ajax, try sending it as a blob. This answer uses FormData [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22621393/3585500) which is not supported in older browsers. The older way is to use an Iframe.