# Receive JSON response while POST urlencoded

Tags: php, json, post

I want to receive and decode JSON response after submitting urlencoded request by POST.
But all I got ($content) after running below  is garbled characters.
I believe the server returns correct values (I checked via hurl.it)

PHP code is below.

```
$target_url = "http://examples.com/send";]
$headers = array(
    'Host: examples.com',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
    'Accept-Language: en-us',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'User-Agent: Appcelerator Titanium/3.5.0',
);
$data = array(
    'id' => 'hogehoge',
    'command' => 'renew'
);

$options = array('http' => array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($data),
    'header' => implode("\r\n", $headers),
));

$contents = file_get_contents($target_url, false, stream_context_create($options));
echo $contents;
```

Headers of response is

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 32
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: ***** GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
```

When I echo $contents, I got

```
�ｫV*J-.ﾍ)Qｲ2ｬﾜｩp0
```

although it should be

```
{"result":1}
```

Thanks in advance.

ADD:
When I `var_dump(json_decode($contents))`,I got `NULL`

Comment: `gzip` you must unzip it.

Comment: note: `Content-Encoding: gzip`. you got json, it's just gzipped.

Comment: `$target_url = "http://examples.com/send";]` i think it must be `$target_url = "http://examples.com/send";` may be a TYPO?

Comment: Or remove `'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response, server is informing you that it is sending zipped content, you must unzip it.

```
Content-encoding: gzip
```

You can use gzdecode() to unzip gzip.

```
echo gzdecode($content);
```

Comment: Just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895852/uncompress-gzip-compressed-http-response

Answer (score 0):

unzip the content:

```
echo gzdecode($contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a gziped string as pointed by the header `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

You can uncompress it using php or js.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php

https://github.com/gcanu/gzip.js