# Creating an image upload API

Tags: php, image, api, upload

I want to make an image upload API 
Example:http://mysite.com/api.php?url=http://test.com/1.jpg
How to write a script can get the image URL from the URL?
Also check.the extension of the image
Then upload to my site and redirect to the image.
Thanks.

Comment: We won't help you until you try something and get stuck.

Comment: if I may, why are you trying to re-invent the wheel when you already have N jquery based api(s) doing the same for you? e.g. blueimp?

Comment: I tried many way to do it,eg.substr.but not working

Comment: I already have a jQuery signal upload script,but I don't know how to get the image URL from the post URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have api.php run a cURL command on your server to get the URL of the file submitted to your API then download the file where you want. Have it then return the location of the image to your script for final processing to include renaming and any database storage you want to accomplish.

Comment: Can i do this without db&curl?

Comment: If you can that would be news to me. You would need cURL to process the image fetch - or maybe use exec() and wget. I have never tried the latter but give it a shot.

Why wouldn't you want to store the image information in the database? There seems to be a lot of information you could collect for analysis and reporting later.

Comment: In PHP file can be read over the network into a string with file_get_contents function, no need for cURL or wget. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: True... I guess this StackOverflow article makes it as easy at it can be...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url-using-php