# How to copy a file without overwriting the destination file?

Tags: php, file

The script I made is.

```
<?php

$source_file = 'http://www.domain.tld/directory/img.png'; 
$dest_file = '/home/user/public_html/directory/directory/img.png'; 

copy($source_file, $dest_file);

?>
```

I need that image to not be delete and reuploaded every time the script is running. I would either want it to be img1.png, img2.png, img3.png, etc. Or img(Date,Time).png, img(Date,Time).png, etc. Is this possible and if so, how do I do this?

Comment: I just got back, so I will try those now. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're concerned with overwriting a file, you could just drop in a timestamp to ensure uniqueness:

```php
$dest_file = '/home/user/public_html/directory/directory/img.png';

// /home/user/public_html/directory/directory/img1354386279.png
$dest_file = preg_replace("/\.[^\.]{3,4}$/i", time() . "$0", $dest_file);
```

Of if you wanted simpler numbers, you could take a slightly more tasking route and change the destination file name as long as a file with that name already exists:

```
$file = "http://i.imgur.com/Z92wU.png";
$dest = "nine-guy.png";

while (file_exists($dest)) {
    $dest = preg_replace_callback("/(\d+)?(\.[^\.]+)$/", function ($m) {
        return ($m[1] + 1) . $m[2];
    }, $dest);
}

copy($file, $dest);
```

You may need to be using a later version of PHP for the anonymous function callback; I tested with 5.3.10 and everything worked just fine.

Comment: And where do I add that in the script, and what do I have to change other then the directory?

Comment: @user1861331 These are drop-in replacements. They will merely change the `$dest_file` path to a unique one for you.

Comment: @user1861331 What is not working? I've updated my answer with a solution that I've tested and confirmed to work.

Comment: No its working, I can't believe Ive been trying to fix this for like an hour, to release I spelled my username wrong...

Comment: +1 for the excellent idea "just drop in a timestamp to ensure uniqueness" ... might be all you need in certain cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$source_file = 'http://www.domain.tld/directory/img.png'; 
$dest_file = '/home/user/public_html/directory/directory/img.png'; 
if(!is_file($dest_file)){
copy($source_file, $dest_file);
}
else{
$fname = end(explode('/',$dest_file));
$fname = time().'-'.$fname;
$dest_file = dirname($dest_file).'/'.$fname;
copy($source_file,$dest_file);
}
?>
```

use this code
This will add time before filename

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP. First time it copies, second time it renames, third time it will copy again because you renamed it and the original no longer exists, and the cycle will continue ad-infinitum...

Comment: you can use rand() function replace it with time()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rename().](https://www.php.net/rename)

**For Example:**

```
rename ("/var/www/files/file.txt", "/var/www/sites/file1.txt");
```

**Or**
You can also use [copy](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

```
$source_file = 'http://www.domain.tld/directory/img.png'; 
$dest_file = '/home/user/public_html/directory/directory/img.png'; 
if(!is_file($dest_file)){
copy($source_file, $dest_file);
}
```

Or if you want to add time it ,you can try like this.

```
 $source="http://www.domain.tld/directory/";
 $destn ="/home/user/public_html/directory/directory/";
 $filename="image.png";
 $ex_name = explode('.',$filename));
 $newname = $ex_name[0].'-'.time().$ex_name[1]; //where $ex_name[0] is filename and $ex_name[1] is extension.
 
 copy($source.filename,$destn.$newname );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$source_file = 'http://www.domain.tld/directory/img.png'; 
$dest_file = '/home/user/public_html/directory/directory/img'.uniqid().'.png'; 
copy($source_file, $dest_file);
```

uniquid gives you a unique Id which is rarely possible to overwrite...

also i would make folders for each month or related to the id of the image

like

```
mkdir(ceil($imgId / 1000), 0777);
```

Comment: Warning: copy(...) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ... on line 6

Comment: in this case your source_file doesnt exist or is not accessable.. check the permissions or maybe try another way of downloading the image first

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url-using-php

to be sure that you dont overwrite the same file over and over again you can use uniqid()