# Saving an image from a PHP URL using curl and PHP

Tags: php

I have tried to download an image from a PHP link. When I try the link in a browser it downloads the image. I enabled curl and I set “allow_url_fopen” to true. I’ve used the methods discussed here [Saving image from PHP URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url-using-php) but it didn’t work. I've  tried "file_get_contents" too, but it didn't work.
I made few changes, but still it doesn’t work. This is the code

```
$URL_path='http://…/index.php?r=Img/displaySavedImage&id=68';
$ch = curl_init ($URL_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$raw=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$fp = fopen($path_tosave.'temp_ticket.jpg','wb');
fwrite($fp, $raw);
fclose($fp);
```

Do you have any idea to make it works? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Is the semicolonn the error ?

Comment: What exactly is the error displayed?

Comment: There isn't any syntax error. Every time an empty image saves on the hard drive but when I try the link in the browser, it downloads the image.

Comment: look at my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    if( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {
      //set the index url
      $source  = file_get_contents('http://…/index.php?r=Img/displaySavedImage&id=68');
      $filestr = "temp_ticket.jpg";
      $fp = fopen($filestr, 'wb');
      if ($fp !== false) {
        fwrite($fp, $source);
        fclose($fp);
      }
      else {
        // File could not be opened for writing
      }
    }
    else {
      // allow_url_fopen is disabled
      // See here for more information:
      // http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen
    }
?>
```

This is what I used to save an image without an extension (dynamic image generated by server). Hope it works for you. Just make sure that the **file path location** is fully qualified and points to an image. As @ComFreek pointed out, you can use `file_put_contents` which is the equivalent to calling `fopen(), fwrite() and fclose()` successively to write data to a file. [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: Don't use the '@' operator in order to hide errors! It is *very* slow.

Comment: I've improved the code a little bit. But why don't you use `file_put_contents()`? It's the same as calling `fopen(), fwrite() and fclose()`.

Comment: @ComFreek good observation. I did not know of such a function as of today, so thanks. I'll leave it like that so the one asking the question see what's going on and let him have a piece of action using `file_put_contents`.

Comment: @MhSalim are you sure it's not your link that's invalid ? What's the output anyways ?

Comment: The link is valid, when I try that in a browser, I will have the image (700 KB). But when I try the code, I only have an empty image (1KB)

Comment: @MhSalim It is possible that the server (where the image is hosted) rejects any requests without appropriate (=from real browsers) header tags. You could emulate this behaviour with cURL but before doing so, I would verify whether this is really the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it as a function :

```
function getFile($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $tmp = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($tmp != false){
        return $tmp;
    }
}
```

And to call it :

```
$content = getFile(URL);
```

Or save its content to a file :

```
file_put_contents(PATH, getFile(URL));
```

Comment: Try now, I have added CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION .. maybe your URL triggers a redirect too.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, I guess it should be some thing about server side,
instead of that I open the blob from the database to write it to a temp file.

Comment: Is that URL on your own server?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing quote and semicolon on the first line:

```
$URL_path='http://…/index.php?r=Img/displaySavedImage&id=68';
```

Also, your URL is in `$URL_path` but you initialise `cURL` with `$path_img` which is undefined  based on the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why use cURL when `file_get_contents()` does the job?

```
<?php

    $img = 'http://…/index.php?r=Img/displaySavedImage&id=68';

    $data = file_get_contents( $img );

    file_put_contents( 'img.jpg', $data );

?>
```

Comment: Because cURL is a hell of a lot faster

Comment: file_get_contests may be disabled for external use on some servers

Comment: @SorinTrimbitas He did say he's set `allow_url_fopen` to true, so it couldn't be that.

Comment: Usually a general solution is preferred to one that works only on some parts.