# Saving image straight to directory in PHP?

Tags: php

I have an image file. Example: http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-random-31108109-500-502.jpg

I want to save the image to a directory called images-folder in my host. What would be the best way to do this using PHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url-using-php

Comment: http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/php/php-save-images-using-curl/ "`imagecreatefromjpeg($img);` where $img is a url for an external image" The site itself deals with the 'what if your host disabled this'

Comment: Thank you guy's you all helped allot and I have exactly what I need now because of the help, I am relay grateful :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is very simple. Here is a little [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) script to do just that:

```
$image_link = "http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-random-31108109-500-502.jpg";//Direct link to image
$split_image = pathinfo($image_link);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $image_link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$response= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$file_name = "images-folder/".$split_image['filename'].".".$split_image['extension'];
$file = fopen($file_name , 'w') or die("X_x");
fwrite($file, $response);
fclose($file);
```

This should do what you want. It will save the image to the directory and then name the image as `random-random-31108109-500-502`<-filename `.jpg`<-extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Its working..

Answer (score 8):

Even simpler without [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL):

```
<?php
    $link= "http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-random-31108109-500-502.jpg";
    $destdir = 'images-folder/';
    $img=file_get_contents($link);
    file_put_contents($destdir.substr($link, strrpos($link,'/')), $img);
?>
```

Comment: using this way will cause an image damage unable to open

Answer (score 1):

Here is another, somewhat easier to follow, example, straight from the site I commented

```
$remote_img = 'http://www.somwhere.com/images/image.jpg';
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_img);
$path = 'images/';
imagejpeg($img, $path);
```

http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/php/php-save-images-using-curl/

Comment: Explain the downvote, please.

Comment: I don't see why you got down voted either your solution work's good , I will up vote you because your answer is genuine.

Comment: You don't need to read the file as an image to download the image. You're allocating all of that memory and creating an editable image buffer with all of the overhead associated with that JUST to save the image. That will not scale. Also you're introducing a security risk by asking PHP to interpret a remote file as a JPEG. libjpeg exploits aren't unknown. These are the reasons I downvoted.