# Save png file locally from a URL in PHP

Tags: php, favicon

I have to download a png file and use it for Image Processing in php.
I want to save this image:
/favicon?domain=http://facebook.com/">https://plus.google.com//favicon?domain=http://facebook.com/ 
into my local folder and perform image processing operations over it.

When I am doing this, its working fine:

```
$url = 'http://s.wordpress.org/about/images/color-blue.png';
$img = 'try1.png';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

but this is not working a file try1.png is getting created of 0kb

```
$url = "https://plus.google.com/_/favicon?domain=http://facebook.com/";
$img = 'try1.png';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

Please help.
Regards, 
Suyash

Comment: change `https` to `http` -- that is if you are getting the error `Unable to find the wrapper "https"...`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url-using-php

Comment: @DaveChen Tried that too.. not working!

Comment: SOLVED : in the php.ini file added this lines:

extension=php_openssl.dll

allow_url_include = On

Comment: http://phptooltip.blogspot.in/2013/05/save-image-from-remote-sitecurl.html

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<?php

$url = "https://plus.google.com/_/favicon?domain=http://facebook.com/";
$img = 'try1.png';

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);  

file_put_contents($img, $result);

?>
```

Comment: I am trying to save favicons from google api using your code but it doesn't work. Could it be something with my php configuration?