# Data migration with PHP

Tags: php, phpquery

If I were using youtube for an example, 
`$link = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYVVCRqTz1Q"`

In the source code of `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYVVCRqTz1Q` we can find

```
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/hYVVCRqTz1Q/hqdefault.jpg?feature=og">
```

I would like php to use `$link` to obtain `$thumbnail` where

```
$thumbnail = "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/hYVVCRqTz1Q/hqdefault.jpg"
```

Comment: you would use something like phpQuery

Comment: See these 2 posts:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url-using-php

Comment: What has this to do with data migration or data mining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $link = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYVVCRqTz1Q';

Now match if the URL is a valid Youtube Link by matching it with Pattern.

```
$ypattern= "#(http://www.youtube.com)?/(v/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)|watch\?v\=([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*?)#";
if(preg_match_all($ypattern,$link, $output))
{ 
    foreach ($output[4] AS $video_id)
    {
```

**Youtube Headers**

```
$headers = get_headers('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $video_id)`;

     if (strpos($headers[0], '200'))
     {
    $youtube = simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$video_id.'?v=1');
            $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$video_id.'?v=2&alt=jsonc'));
```

**Thumbnail** >

```
$thumbnail = $json->data->thumbnail->sqDefault;
                }
            }
        }
```