# upload photos got by fql query on my server

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello guys i'm trying to understand how to upload the image from facebook.

function for do fql query. Is useful for future occasions.

```
 <?php
      // connection facebook api key...
      function fb_fql($fql) {
                $this->ci =& get_instance();
            // Get User Details
            $this->ci->load->model('facebook_model');
            $this->ci->load->library('user');



            // $fb_id = $this->ci->user->get_facebook_id($this->ci->session->userdata('user_id'));
            // User is found

                // Get Facebook User profile
                $user_profile = $this->ci->facebook->getUser();
                $result = false;
                    if ($user_profile) { // if profile exist
                        try{

                          $accessToken = $this->ci->facebook->getAccessToken();
                          $fb_id = $this->ci->facebook->api('/me?access_token='.$accessToken); 
                          if( isset($user_profile) )
                            {
                          $fql_run = array(
                                'method' => 'fql.query', 
                                'query' => $fql,
                            );
                            $result = $this->ci->facebook->api($fql_run); // run fql
                            } else { $result = false; }
                        }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
                            $result = null;
                        }       

                     }
                    return $result;

        }

?>
```

Here i get the photos by this query and the result of the array show correctly 10 photos of facebook. Now i have to upload it on my server but how can i do that?

```
<?php
              // fql query
              $fql = "SELECT pid 
                  FROM photo 
                  WHERE aid IN (
                      SELECT aid 
                      FROM album 
                      WHERE owner=me() LIMIT 10
                  ) ";
                // run query
                $photos = $this->facebook_action->fb_fql($fql);
                if ($photos != false) {
                  foreach ($photos as $photo) {
                      echo print_r($photos); // show the array with the data taken
                      // here i would like upload the photos got from the query.
                  }
                } else {
                  echo "no photo";
                }

             ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get the src or src_big field from the photo table and then download this using CURL, file_put_contents or similar. There are quite a few StackOverflow answers for grabbing an image and saving it to a file - e.g [Saving image from PHP URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url-using-php)

```
SELECT src_big FROM photo 
WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album  WHERE owner=me() LIMIT 10)
```

Since you will be downloading user's data to your own server, I would advise you to check that your application does not violate the [Facebook Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).