# i am generating qr code to browser how do i save that to a folder in php

Tags: php

i used this code to save image file.  but its returning an empty file .

function save_from_url($inPath,$outPath)
{

```
$in=    fopen($inPath, "rb");
$out=   fopen($outPath, "wb");
while ($chunk = fread($in,8192))
{
    fwrite($out, $chunk, 8192);
}
fclose($in);
fclose($out);
```

}

save_from_url('url/eg.php','flw.png');

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving image from PHP URL using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url-using-php)

Answer (score 2):

Does your server have [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) turned on?

If it does, using [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) and [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.file-put-contents.php) is quite simple:

```
$in = file_get_contents('http://example.com/image.php');
file_put_contents('file.png', $in);
```

If not, you will have to use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/fr/ref.curl.php):

```
$in = curl_init('http://example.com/image.php');
$out = fopen('file.png', 'wb');
curl_setopt($in, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);
curl_setopt($in, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($in);
curl_close($in);
fclose($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply copy it from a remote URL:

`copy('http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png', '/tmp/google.png');`