# How do I grab images and save to local machine using xpath and php?

Tags: php, xpath

I am scraping data from an html site and need to grab not just text but images too. Is it possible with xpath to actually grab the image file and download to my local machine as I am grabbing the textual content? I am using a php script.

Answer (score 1):

XPath will get the address of the image, with something like `//img[@id='image-id']/@src`. When you have the address of the image, e.g. `http://external-server.com/path/to/image.png`, you make PHP download it as it's done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url-using-php)