# Display all logged in users

Tags: javascript, php, api, google-api

I have used this tutorial for 'sign in with google' on my website.
http://tutorialzine.com/2012/08/build-a-one-click-registration-form-powered-by-google/

I am not a programmer really but just download the code in there and followed the steps in there. It works fine.
Now I want all logged in users with their profile pic displayed as a list. This should be visible to anyone on the website. If a user logs out, he should be removed from the list. Can someone point me to an article or help me please?

[My website login page](http://spooster.com/google-login-form/index.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **need to learn** little bit of programming to do so..
first you need to create a `database table` which will store the `value for logged in users`..
I checked the code , so when a user loggs in to your website than his `user_id` is been saved to the `session_variable`.. so you can insert his/her `user_id` to your database table and you can use a `login flag` lets say `true or false` so if the `user_id` is there in the `session_variable` than the flag should be `true` and when the user loggs out than you can `update the flag to false`.. So by using this you can achive your desired thing. .
**but some developing knowledge is must to do so..**

Comment: thanks! this gives me a direction to move in. i'll probably get a developer do this for me if i am not able to. Currently the database does not store the user's google profile image but only has a URL pointing to some Google's domain. You checked the code, looking at it, will google allow to pull a user's profile pic using that url even when the user is not logged in to my website? Hope I am making sense.

Comment: yes you can.. Please have a look at this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url-using-php

Comment: I don't want to save a copy of the image. I just want to know if I am allowed to fetch the image of a google account holder from google's servers even when that user is not logged in to my website.

Comment: just try putting `user's profile image URL` to your browser link.. and if the link shows user image without any error than you can... :)