# php image upload from url and resize

Tags: php

i have this upload form and i want to resize image when uploaded
its upload form from url i did it from file upload but cant for url upload
can anyone help me?

```
<?php
    if($_POST["sub"]){
        $url = trim($_POST["url"]);
        if($url){
            $file = fopen($url,"rb");
            if($file){
                $directory = "../images/news/";
                $valid_exts = array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png");
                $ext = substr(basename($url), strrpos(basename($url), '.'));
                $ext = str_replace('.','',$ext);
                if(in_array($ext,$valid_exts)){
                    $rand = rand(0,9999999999);
                    $filename = $rand.'.'.$ext;
                    $newfile = fopen($directory . $filename, "wb");
                    if($newfile){
                        while(!feof($file)){
                            fwrite($newfile,fread($file,1024 * 8),1024 * 8);
                        }
                        echo ''."";
                        echo ''.$filename.'';
                    } else { echo 'Could not establish new file ('.$directory.$filename.') on local server. Be sure to CHMOD your directory to 777.'; }
                } else { echo 'Invalid file type. Please try another file.'; }
            } else { echo 'Could not locate the file: '.$url.''; }
        } else { echo 'Invalid URL entered. Please try again.'; }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GD or Image Magic library to resize image:

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

Answer (score 0):

For saving the file from URL:

If you have allow_url_fopen set to true:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/image.php';
$img = '/my/folder/flower.gif';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

Else use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/image.php');
$fp = fopen('/my/folder/flower.gif', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

This is the same as the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url) post...