# Javascript - how to take a snap shot from <img> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, google-chrome

With Google Chrome browser, i have this element: `<img id=copyfromme src="http://192.168.0.2/axis/video.mjpeg" />` running, which shows a live video 4 frames per second from an embedded security camera.

Now i need to take a snap-shot (copy one frame from "copyfromme"), and save it as png or jpeg to mysql server.

How can i copy the snap-shot?

Comment: You can create a script (vb,bat,php etc ) which hits the URL : `http://192.168.0.2/axis/video.mjpeg` and save the response to any folder and make corresponding entry in mysql.

Comment: Might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url

Comment: I would suggest you to draw that image on the canvas and send base 64 data to server and manipulate it...