# Uploading an image to Parse from a URL

Tags: javascript, php, parse-platform

In my webapp I'm using the Noun Project API to create an icon picker for something they're creating. However, the Noun Project API gives me a URL to the icon that expires some time later. Ideally I can save the image to my Parse backend from the URL I'm given, but I have no idea how.

My assumption would've been to insert it into a file `<input>`, but apparently HTML won't allow that. If I could create a File object from the URL image then I could save that easily, but I couldn't figure out how to do that either.

If anyone has any idea how to save a remote image to Parse, I would greatly appreciate your input. Any and all solutions are welcome, pure JS or anything -- even PHP, I'm getting desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using php its fairly easy.  One way is to use curl

```
$ch = curl_init($yoururl);
$fp = fopen('/my/folder/flower.gif', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer taken from [Saving image from PHP URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url).  There are more options there as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I get you right but you can simply do that by adding a `<a>` tag and set the download prop of it to the url you want and finally call the click method of it. something like this:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = filename; 
a.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
delete a;
```

Comment: Interesting. Will try that out shortly.