# Recloning a json-document by scheudule

Tags: php, json, web-services, cpanel

I have a json-document on my host called: "weatherData.json". The data in that data is going to be cloned from another page called: "*www.example.com/whatWeather.json*".

The "wheaterData.json" on my host should be **recloned** from the **external page** automaticly every 10 minutes. 
*(I have cpanel if that's make any difference)*

**What would be the most optimal way to accomplish this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a cron job. (In cpanel, there's a link to 'Cron Jobs')

Simplest way to do that is to create a URL that handles the import (I am assuming you are using a framework with some routing capabilities, for example http://yoursite.com/handle-import to point to the import function)

Then set the cron command to

```
curl http://yoursite.com/handle-import
```

You also have a nice interface which hepls you set up the recurrence interval (start with the default "every 5 minutes" and just edit the 5 into 10
`

As for the cloning itself, you can check out [Saving image from PHP URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url)