# Issue displaying json feed items using PHP

Tags: php, json

I am very new to json in combination with php and wonder why the following code is not working. My mission is displaying the title items one by one.

```
<?php
$json_string =    file_get_contents("https://www.fiverr.com/gigs/gigs_as_json?host=search&type=single_query&query_string=pet&search_filter=rating&category_id=3&sub_category_id=49&limit=48");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);
$parsed_json = $parsed_json['gigs'];

foreach($parsed_json as $key => $value)
{
   echo $value['title'] . '<br>';
}
?>
```

The next issue will by, how would I be able to save the image item called cloud_img_med to my server into /grabbed

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about why this code isn't working:

I tried to set it up myself, and found out that the output fetched by file_get_contents is compressed. You can see that by reading the output in a simple var_dump:

```
var_dump($json_string);
```

To fix this, you'll need to use a custom context with no compression:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => "GET",
            'header' => "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=0, compress;q=0\r\n",
        )
));
```

Then pass it as the third parameter:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("https://www.fiverr.com/gigs/gigs_as_json?host=search&type=single_query&query_string=pet&search_filter=rating&category_id=3&sub_category_id=49&limit=48", false, $context);
```

I should do this JSON string readable

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to work fine - I tried it on my local machine.

Running this

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOT
// JSON here...
EOT;

$parsed_json = json_decode($str, true);
$parsed_json = $parsed_json['gigs'];

foreach($parsed_json as $key => $value)
{
   echo $value['title'] . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Gives me this output

```
replace the MGM lion with your pet or whoever<br>design creative Animal And Pet Company logo<br>`
```

Which is sort of what you want? If you're having trouble, maybe `file_get_contents` isn't allowed on your server and you can't get the JSON. Try hardcoding it into the $str variable like I did, and see if you get what you want.

With regards to saving the image, you can check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/724449/4396258

Comment: Hmm nice observation, I'll check out the file_get_contents permissions on my server :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be the data you're getting from Fiverr's JSON API. At least in my test, I found it was using `gzip` encoding to compress the data you're requesting. So you have to uncompress it.

```
$json_string = file_get_contents("https://www.fiverr.com/gigs/gigs_as_json?host=search&type=single_query&query_string=pet&search_filter=rating&category_id=3&sub_category_id=49&limit=48");
$content = json_decode(gzinflate( substr($json_string,10,-8) ));
$gigs = $content->gigs;
foreach($gigs as $key => $value)
{
   echo $value->title . '<br>';
}
```