# Can I use file_put_contents() to populate $_FILES?

Tags: php, curl, file-upload, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

The goal:

I have a URL of an image. I would like to get the image file and to upload it to `$_FILES` as if the image was uploaded by a client.

The reason:

I need this because I have a form in which users can either upload an image file in a `input type="file"` field OR enter an image URL in a `input type="text"` field and later, when I validate the form, I want the validation function to access the file using `$_FILES` regardless the method the user chose to supply the image (either by uploading a file or by entering a file URL.)

The problem:

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url) answer on using `file_put_contents()` and `file_get_contents()` but I don't understand if I can use it to change `$_FILES` and if yes then how.

EDIT:

After reading David's comment, I understood my mistake. What I actually need is a way to download a file from a URL using `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` to the same temporary location on the server that uploaded files are downloaded to. By that I would be able to handle files the same way regardless of how they got there (URL or file upload).

Comment: The answer you linked is clearly telling you to use `curl`. If you'll be using outsource image, you have to fetch it with curl and won't be needing to do anything with `$_FILES`, that just handles uploaded files.

Comment: It sounds like the validation function shouldn't be relying on `$_FILES`.  Can both the uploaded file and the downloaded file be homogenized to a common format for validation?

Comment: @David Yes, in both cases I can download the image to the server and then validate it but I try to avoid downloading a file before it has been validated by the function. I am using WordPress and I want the file to stay in $_FILES until validated and only afterwards to move it to a directory on the server. Does it make sense or am I missing some simple solution here?