# Get all images and return the src

Tags: php, regex, simple-html-dom

My code bellow grabs some content. in this content there are some photos.
How can i loop through this content find all images and return their src?

my code so far:

```
$items = $html->find('div.post-single-content',0)->children(1)->outertext;
foreach($items $node) { 
$node->find('img');
}
print_r ($node);
```

Comment: foreach($items as $node) should work, assuming that you targeted element successfully....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use regex, use a parser. Example:

```
$string = '<img src="You want this" style="width:200px;" />';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
     echo $image->getAttribute('src') . "\n";
}
```

Output:

> You want this

Comment: EXCELLENT @chris85 !!!!!! I have one question... how easy is now to upload the photos to folder "images" and replace each of them with new uploaded url?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. This is only pulling the `src`s from an `HTML` page... maybe the `rename` function is what you are looking for, http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php?

Comment: Lets  say that we have the string $string = 'kitty <img src="www.mystiter.uk/image1.jpg" style="width:200px;" /> and dog  <img src="www.mystiter.uk/image2.jpg" style="width:200px;" />'; How is it possible to upload this 2 photos to another directory and replace each src with the new (new upload directory). Images are from another website and i want to upload it to my server

Comment: Are you trying to copy images from a server that isn't yours to your server, or are the images already on your server and you want to move them? If the former,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url. If the latter take off the text preceding the TLD and replace it with the server path to the web dir. Then use the rename function.

Comment: check this out 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32928588/find-all-images-upload-them-and-replace-with-new