# PHP - Copy Image From Another URL

Tags: php

Alright I have a simple question that I can't figure out 
How can I make

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://www.url.com/image.jpg');
file_put_contents('/images/image.jpg', $image); //Where to save the image on your server
```

To where I can set the `$image` variable using a html form where people can submit a link using the `$_GET[""]` method instead of having to change the link in the php file manually?

Comment: @abrad1212, `$image = file_get_contents($_GET['url']);`, but only after you sanitize `$_GET['url']` to avoid problem with people that submit `?url=index.php` or similar

Comment: If the image is larger it is going to cause memory problems.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url

Comment: @Federico What do you mean about Sanitize $_GET["url"] can you give me a example or something?

Comment: abrad1212, I don't think that you want people to choose `../../../../etc/passwd` as an url. Maybe you want check that the url start always with `http(s)://`

Comment: @Federico Ok but how would I go about sanitizing this can you give me a link or a example (sorry complete noob right here) -EDIT-is this a good tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters--net-2595

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've a form like this:

```
<form>
    URL: <input name="url">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then you can retrieve the url submitted with `$_GET['url']`:

```
$image = file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
file_put_contents('/images/image.jpg', $image);
```

Anyhow, you must be careful on Local File Inclusion, because without further checks  the users can choose path like `/etc/passwd`, `../configuration.php`, etc, and if `/images/image.jpg` can be view by the users, they can read file that shouldn't see.

A thing that you may want do is check if the `$_GET['url`]` is a valid url. You can do that with:

```
if (!filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The url is not valid.');
}
```

but that's not enough since `file:///etc/passwd` is a valid url. So, instead, just be sure that the url start with `http://` or `https://`.

```
$isValid = false;
foreach(['http://', 'https://'] as $schema) {
    if (strpos($_GET['url'], $schema) === 0) {
        $isValid = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($isValid && filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    $image = file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
    file_put_contents('/images/image.jpg', $image); //Where to save the image on your server
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Federico

[image: First]

[image: Second]

Sorry I don't have a lot of time to format the code I'm on my phone uploading everything to my FTP server as I'm traveling
So sorry if everything is to cramped

EDIT: I see the ! on the second pic and removed it so don't worry

Comment: don't submit an answer, just write a comment. have you a question/problem?

Comment: Sorry Im new to this, the sanitizing worked but the image IS NOT SAVING at all, any help is needed

Comment: `/images/image.jpg` is the absolute path. you may want replace it with `__DIR__ . '/images/image.jpg'`

Comment: Nope still not working ;( Damn this is giving me a damn headache, the URL will be sanitized but it is still not saving the image ;( Take a careful look at my code see if I would have messed anything else other than what you said I fixed!!!

Comment: you may don't have the write permission in `/images/`. Enable you php error, put `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', true);` on top of the file.

Comment: @Federico On the Index.php file?

Comment: yup. check if you see an error when you submit the form

Comment: I'm getting this Warning: file_put_contents(C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.18-0\apache2\htdocs\Experimental\SaveImages\External Testing/imgs/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.18-0\apache2\htdocs\Experimental\SaveImages\External Testing\test.php on line 25

Comment: It's giving me the error here:  if                                     ($isValid && filter_var($_GET['URL'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {     $image = file_get_contents($_GET['URL']);     file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/imgs/', $image); //Where to save the image on your server } ?>

Comment: change `file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/imgs/', $image);` to `file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/imgs/somefilename.jpg', $image);`

Comment: @Federico YES THANK YOU.... I don't have enough reputation to upvote your comment soooo crap but THANK YOU

Comment: You can test it here http://abrad1212.ddns.net/Experimental/SaveImages/External%20Testing/test.php/       If you want thanks