# Upload image from URL to Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm wondering how to upload file onto Firebase's storage via URL instead of input (for example). I'm scrapping images from a website and retrieving their URLS. I want to pass those URLS through a foreach statement and upload them to Firebase's storage. Right now, I have the firebase upload-via-input working with this code:

```
var auth = firebase.auth();
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();
 var file = evt.target.files[0];


  var metadata = {
    'contentType': file.type
  };

  // Push to child path.
  var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' + file.name).put(file, metadata);

  // Listen for errors and completion of the upload.
  // [START oncomplete]
  uploadTask.on('state_changed', null, function(error) {
    // [START onfailure]
    console.error('Upload failed:', error);
    // [END onfailure]
  }, function() {
    console.log('Uploaded',uploadTask.snapshot.totalBytes,'bytes.');
    console.log(uploadTask.snapshot.metadata);
    var url = uploadTask.snapshot.metadata.downloadURLs[0];
    console.log('File available at', url);
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    document.getElementById('linkbox').innerHTML = '<a href="' +  url + '">Click For File</a>';}
```

Question what do I replace

> var file = evt.target.files[0];

with to make it work with external URL instead of a manual upload process?

var file = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/oonjz.jpg"; doesn't work!

Comment: There is no need to store them (maybe not possible) using storage. The links are strings, store them in the database like you would all other data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no need to use Firebase Storage if all you're doing is saving a url path. Firebase Storage is for physical files, while the Firebase Realtime Database could be used for structured data.

**Example . once you get the image url from the external site this is all you will need :**

```
var externalImageUrl = 'https://foo.com/images/image.png';
```

then you would store this in your json structured database:

```
databaseReference.child('whatever').set(externalImageUrl);
```

**OR**

If you want to actually download the physical images straight from external site to storage then this will require making an http request and receiving a blob response or probably may require a server side language ..

Javascript Solution : [How to save a file from a url with javascript](https://web.archive.org/web/20180211190233/https://ausdemmaschinenraum.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/how-to-save-a-file-from-a-url-with-javascript/)

PHP Solution : [Saving image from PHP URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url)

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying! I am trying to save the physical image! I'm going to try out the suggestions you gave!

Comment: No problem! I played around with this a little my myself and came up with this : http://codepen.io/theConstructor/pen/vKNRdE

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to get it to work with Firebase but it's acting crazy haha. Is this right?        var uploadTask = storageRef.child('trial/' + filename).put.xhr('GET', url);

Comment: AHHHH! I figured it out. You were so HELPFUL! The only issue I'm having now is it keeps saying No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Yes , you may get this error for a number of reasons . Try running your project on a server if not already .

Comment: Bless you! Thanks :)

Comment: Hi HalesEnchanted, can you share your solution to upload images from URLs to Firebase Storage ?

Comment: Hi HalesEnchanted, can you share your solution?

Answer (score 12):

Javascript solution to this using fetch command.

```
var remoteimageurl = "https://example.com/images/photo.jpg"
var filename = "images/photo.jpg"

fetch(remoteimageurl).then(res => {
  return res.blob();
}).then(blob => {
    //uploading blob to firebase storage
  firebase.storage().ref().child(filename).put(blob).then(function(snapshot) {
    return snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
 }).then(url => {
   console.log("Firebase storage image uploaded : ", url); 
  }) 
}).catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Answer (score 10):

[This answer](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/506#issuecomment-436403257) is similar to @HalesEnchanted's answer but with less code. In this case it's done with a Cloud Function but I assume the same can be done from the front end. Notice too how `createWriteStream()` has an options parameter similar to `bucket.upload()`.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('my-bucket');
const file = bucket.file('path/to/image.jpg');

fetch('https://example.com/image.jpg').then((res: any) => {
  const contentType = res.headers.get('content-type');
  const writeStream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType,
      metadata: {
        myValue: 123
      }
    }
  });
  res.body.pipe(writeStream);
});
```

Comment: `node-fetch` requires an older version for this example to work now. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70727579/1081447)

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this helps somebody else :)

```
    // Download a file form a url.
 function saveFile(url) {
 // Get file name from url.
  var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).split("?")[0];
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
xhr.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
xhr.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled);

  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); // xhr.response is a blob
    a.download = filename; // Set the file name.
    a.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    delete a;

          if (this.status === 200) {
        // `blob` response
        console.log(this.response);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {

                    var auth = firebase.auth();
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

                     var metadata = {
        'contentType': 'image/jpeg'
      };

                    var file = e.target.result;
                    var base64result = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                    var blob = b64toBlob(base64result);


                       console.log(blob);

                var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' + filename).put(blob, metadata);

                uploadTask.on('state_changed', null, function(error) {
        // [START onfailure]
        console.error('Upload failed:', error);
        // [END onfailure]
      }, function() {
        console.log('Uploaded',uploadTask.snapshot.totalBytes,'bytes.');
        console.log(uploadTask.snapshot.metadata);
        var download = uploadTask.snapshot.metadata.downloadURLs[0];
        console.log('File available at', download);
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        document.getElementById('linkbox').innerHTML = '<a href="' +  download + '">Click For File</a>';
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
      });
            // `data-uri`

        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.response);        
    };
  };



  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
}

function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
  contentType = contentType || '';
  sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

  var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  var byteArrays = [];

  for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }

  var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
  return blob;
}



    function transferComplete(evt) {        


            window.onload = function() {
      // Sign the user in anonymously since accessing Storage requires the user to be authorized.
    auth.signInAnonymously().then(function(user) {
        console.log('Anonymous Sign In Success', user);
        document.getElementById('file').disabled = false;
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Anonymous Sign In Error', error);
      });
    } 
}



function transferFailed(evt) {
  console.log("An error occurred while transferring the file.");
}

function transferCanceled(evt) {
  console.log("The transfer has been canceled by the user.");
}
```