# Is there a special way to upload url images to firebase?

Tags: firebase, axios, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

> Blockquote

I'm building my app in Nuxt and Vuetify and I want to upload url images to Firebase with Axios using inputs (v-file-input). I have no problems with names but when I upload an url image and when I make the get call the response is just the url link, not the picture. So, is there any particular way to upload url pictures?
Is not as simple as any other input?

Thanks in advance.

```
            <template>
       <div>
         <v-app>
         <v-container>
         <h2>Movies</h2>
           <ul>
               <li v-for="movi in moviesData" :key="movi.id">
                        {{movi.name}}
                        {{movi.director}}
                        {{movi.image}}
                  </li>
           </ul>
           </v-container>
           </v-app>
       </div>

       </template>

        <script>
        import axios from 'axios'
        export default {
          data() {
            return {
                moviesData: [],
             }
          },
          methods:{
            getMovies(){
              axios.get('https://proyecto-final-cf888-default- 
     rtdb.firebaseio.com/' + 'movies.json')
                .then( (res)=>{
                  let results=[];
                  console.log(res);
                  for (let id in res.data){
                    console.log(id);
                    console.log(res.data[id]);
                    results.push({
                       id: id, 
                       name: res.data[id].name,
                       director: res.data[id].director,
                       image: res.data[id].image,
                    });
                  }
                  this.moviesData= results;
                  })
                .catch((error)=>{
                  console.log(error) 
                })       
               }
             }, 
            created(){
              this.getMovies();
            }
        }; 
        </script>
```

Comment: Have you checked [Upload image from URL to Firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63174282/13130697)?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: That is because is a general procedure question

Comment: Dharmaraj Yes but it does not work for me because I do need to use input

Comment: @Elisaniza There is no such a thing like URL image. There can be like PNG Image or JPG image, but never URL image. Person who answered you get caught and didn't understand well what you want to do.

Comment: @Elisaniza Dharmaraj sent you a link where you can fetch whole image from other external URL and upload it to firebase Storage. No one mention there about any inputs, so you don't need to use input! All you need is URL from where you can upload a file.

Comment: Ok Mises, I'll translate it next time, but in this case my question was more like a general one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing an URL in Firestore will not store the referenced image itself.

1. You might upload the image to Storage and a reference it in Firestore.
2. Or you store the URL in Firestore and initiate a HTTP-GET request in your app to load the image from the web.

Note:

Firestore limits a single document to 1MB. Many images are larger than that.

Storage also offer functions to scale uploaded images automatically etc.

Answer (score 0):

This was the way:

```
        <li v-for="movi in moviesData" :key="movi.id">
                    {{movi.name}}
                    {{movi.director}}
         <v-img :src='movi.image'></v-img>
              </li>
```

Incredibly simple.

Thanks everyone!