# can't transfer file from external server php

Tags: php, file-transfer

I saw an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/724449/4765380) that said that I could use `copy` to transfer the file. However I tried this, and it didn't work.

```
<?php
  $img = $_GET["img"];
  if($img){
    if(strpos($image, ".jpg") != -1){
      $ext = ".jpg";
    } else if(strpos($image, ".png") != -1){
      $ext = ".png";
    } else if(strpos($image, ".gif") != -1){
      $ext = ".gif";
    } else {
      die("Unsupported image type.");
    }
    $rand = rand(0, 100000);
    if(copy($img, "/images/" . $rand . $ext)){ echo "/images/$rand$ext"; } else { echo "Unsupported image type."; }
  } else {
    echo "Unsupported image type.";
  }
?>
```

The reason, as I found out, is because the `copy` function isn't working. I set the `allow_url_fopen` to `on` in my `php.ini`, so why isn't this working?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Offhand it looks like what you're trying to copy from can't be found: what are your inputs? What is `$img` at the point you're executing `copy`? Maybe put this in a try/catch block to get specific exceptions?

Comment: `Warning: copy(http://example.com/image.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /home/*******/public_html/image.php on line 14`

Comment: So it was just the image that was the problem... is there any way I can get around a HTTP Forbidden?

Comment: "Get around"? No: that code means you're not allowed to get (if it exists) the resource you're requesting.