# php get image from url and save

Tags: php, image, curl, download

I understand there are many questions asking how to do this however none seem to cover what I am after.

See url: https://nz.tradevine.com/BlobStorage/GetFullPhoto?photoID=3591090673176038018&organisationID=3468490059683634443

How can I download this image and save as plug.jpg?

I think this might be different than others because it doesn't have for example .jpg at the end of the url? either way I can't get it to download.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it with below code

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('https://nz.tradevine.com/BlobStorage/GetFullPhoto?photoID=3591090673176038018&organisationID=3468490059683634443');

$myfile = fopen("plug.jpg", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $file);
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

Hope this will help!