# Using PHP to force image download doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, html, image, web, download

I have an image link that is 100% fine. I can use it to link to the image, and I can use it to display the image. However whenever I try to use PHP's headers to force an image download, it doesn't work. Here's what I'm using:

```
            $file = $link;
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"'); 
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            readfile($file);
```

The download starts and asks me where to save the image, as it should. However after the image is downloaded, it simply won't open. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what kind of image is it - is it a png or jpeg? does this have to work for either?

Comment: I have try your code and it's works perfect.. I think problem in your path...Check your path.\

Comment: @WEBjuju Just JPEG.

Comment: @NikhilVaghela I don't see how that is the case. I even used various images from the web to test this, and they all have the same problem.

Comment: Be sure you do not have any additionl output. For example symbol for encoding with BOM. Try to put `exit;` after `readfile`.

Comment: what you mean by saying **it simply won't open** is it corrupted when you are clicking image to open ? what is the size of the image you are able to see?

Comment: can you **echo $file;** ? is it relative path or http ? is should be relative i mean directory path ..

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave What I mean is that no image viewer or editor can open the downloaded image.

It's downloading from an online URL.

Comment: oh, i think he's got a url that displays an image.  i think the image is not local on his server yet.

Comment: @PL200 relative path needs to be used when we are supposed to download image.

Comment: Correct, @WEBjuju

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the image first:

```
        $file = 'newimage.png';
        $file_contents = file_get_contents($link);
        file_put_contents($file, $file_contents);
```

Then you can output the image:

```
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit();
```

Comment: This still has the same problem as I was having.

Comment: try adding an exit after the readfile to be sure nothing else is going on.  why do you have $file = $link.  that seems counterintuitive - what is in $link is it the file path local on your server?

Comment: $link is a URL to a website's image.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave The image is not hosted on my website. It is hosted externally.

Comment: @PL200 then you need to download from http of that server to your server's particular directory and then can open it ...

Comment: @PL200 something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave Interesting. So it's not possible to use this PHP function with an external image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128989/discussion-between-mittul-at-technobrave-and-pl200).