# How to save image from URL in server folder using php or javascript?

Tags: php

I have this image URL (***no extension***):
`https://www.google.com/abc/files/AwAh20isBECxwscp4JiT`

How can I save this image in my server folder?

Comment: Your provided url not opening. And did you try anything to achieving your goal? Please post details.

Comment: if it doesn't have an extension, it's not a image, it's a website that displays a image.

Comment: this is a false URL, just for example purpose.

Comment: Open it in firefox and do rightclick on it. If it shows a dropdown "Inspect Element" click on that and extract the src...

Comment: Quick & dirty solution with php: use `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `file_get_contents($url)`  in order to retrieve the contents of any remote file if you have `allow_url_fopen`   enabled in your PHP configuration.

Once you download the image into memory, then you can save it with

`file_put_contents($img, $imgcontent)`

Example might look like this:

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/abc/files/AwAh20isBECxwscp4JiT';
$img = '/my/folder/flower.gif';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

If you don't allow remote URLs to be opened by `fopen()`, then you have the option of using the `cURL`  functionality to grab files remotely.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/image.php');
$fp = fopen('/my/folder/flower.gif', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Duplicate of: [Saving image from PHP URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url?rq=1)