# single image download without get from database is done How to download multiple image from URL stored in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table containing pictures URL that looks like this:

```
Table:
partno | url
10878  | http://www.pic1.jpg
20477  | http://www.pic2.jpg
and so on (+10000)
```

I want to run a script in order to download all of them on my LOCAL path

I was confusing what could be the most simple way to do it. I wanted to run a PHP script in order to get the URLs from MySQL and then use a PHP command to download each of them, something like this ...please help me

below .. i have done one by one download image by using textbox to search and download

```
// Open the file to get existing content
$data = file_get_contents($file);
$newimage=basename($file);

// New file
$new = 'image/'.$newimage;
// Write the contents back to a new file
file_put_contents($new, $data);
mysql_query("Insert into image set name = '$newimage' ");
echo "<img src='image/$newimage' width='300px' height='250px'/>";
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="url" name="url"/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="subimg" value="submit"/> 
 </form>
```

multiple image download from URL stored in database code..but output will not come..please help me

```
 <?php
 // connection to database
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db('import_exceldata',$con) 
 ?>
 <?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['subimg']))
{
$result=mysql_query("select url from mytask ");
set_time_limit(1000);    
while( $url = $result->fetch() ) {  
// Open the file to get existing content
 $data = file_get_contents($result);
 $newimage=basename($result);
// New file
$new = 'image/'.$newimage;
// Write the contents back to a new file
file_put_contents($new, $data);
}
mysql_query("Insert into image set name = '$newimage' ");
echo "<img src='image/$newimage' width='300px' height='250px'/>";
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="submit" name="subimg" value="retrieve images"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving image from PHP URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url)

Comment: but yours does not understand..i want get multiple url from database and download images

Comment: write a script in php which will connect to mysql database and fetch all urls in one array. Now iterate on this array and use cURL to fetch each url one by one

Comment: It's 2017. PHP's mysql_ API was effective;y deprecated several years ago.

Comment: so ...wat can i do #Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood right, but you can get your file url's from mysql  via the sourcecode below. This would store your data from the table in $row, which you can use. And it echos the whole $row, so you can see the result of the query.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('database_name', $link);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query('SELECT partno, url FROM table_name');
if (!$result) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

//to show what the query got
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo ("name: ").$row['partno'].("<br>");
    echo ("url: ").$row['url'].("<br>");
}
//to store the data in $row
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: this code only show table in all rows.. i want to fetch url one by one and the url run to get multiple image  to stored in local path

Comment: do u know that pls tel me

Comment: Works for me with my table in my mysql database. Did you replace the placeholders? username/pw/... Otherwise i don't understand what you mean. If you want to access $row one by one you could use a for-loop

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use python for this task and write following code

```
import MySQLdb
import urllib

con = MySQLdb.Connect('server', 'username', 'password', 'database')
cursor = con.cursor()
query = "SELECT url FROM table"
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
for url in result:
   urllib.urlretrieve(url[0], "local/address/filename")
```

Comment: i need in php #Cybersupernova

Comment: then do it yourself in this same manner. I ain't going to write code for you