# Save image from url to local machine

Tags: php

I want to save an image from an URL to the user's local machine in PHP. Is this possible? I've been researching for a while, and I can't seem to find the answer. This is my code

```
function Save()
{
   header('Content-Type: image/png');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="thumbnail.png"');
    imagepng("url?");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving image from PHP URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url)

Comment: No, that saves the image to the website server.

Comment: True. Sounds like youll need JS for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force file download with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)

Comment: This is not possible at all in a browser environment - allowing a website arbitrary write access to your disk would be a security nightmare. You can do it if the user in question has PHP on their own machine and runs your script, but that is a very different thing.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a download link that the user clicks on, you can have it re-direct to the url of the file you want to serve directly, the client browser should handle the rest.

If the file needs to be re-served from your system having a php file that sets those headers and then echo's the imagepng output should do it.