# HTML DOM to Download Image from <img> URI

Tags: javascript, java, php, html, dom

I have created a list of all page uris I'd like to download an image from for a vehicle service manual.

The images are delivered via a PHP script,as can be seen here http://www.atfinley.com/service/index.php?cat=g2&page=32

This is probably meant to deter behaviors like my own, however, every single Acura Legend owner shouldn't depend on a single host for their vehicle's manual.

I'd like to design a bot in JS/Java that can visit every url I've stored in this txt document https://pastebin.com/yXdMJipq

To automate the download of the available png at the resource.

I'll eventually be creating a pdf of the manual, and publishing it for open and free use.

If anyone has ideas for libraries I could use, or ways to delve into the solution, please let me know. I am most fluent in Java.

I'm thinking a solution might be to fetch the html document at each url, and download the image from the `<img src>`argument.

Comment: So what issue are you facing exactly?

Comment: There is a `print/save`-Button. You should get the links for you imgs from there

Comment: you could use html parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written something similar but unfortunately, i can't find it anymore. Nevertheless, i remember using the [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) Java-library which comes in pretty handy.

It includes an HTTP-client and you can run CSS-selectors on the document just like with jQuery...

This is the example from their frontpage:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

Creating PDFs is quite tricky, but i use [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/documentcreation.html) for such things...

Comment: Extremely useful for me, thank you so much, was able to find the CSS Selector in Inspector. Literally a copy paste solution to parse the html from the document.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for a JavaScript solution but I believe PHP (which you also added as a tag) is more suitable for the task. Here are some guidelines to get you started:

1. Move all the URLs into an array and create a foreach loop that will iterate on it.
2. Inside the loop use the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to retrieve the image URL attribute for each page.
3. Still inside the loop use the URL for the image in a CURL request to grab the file from that and save it into your custom folder. You can find the code required for this part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url).

If this process proves to be too long and you get a PHP runtime error consider storing the URLs generated by step 2 in a file and then using that file to generate a new array and run step 3 on it as a separate process.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am a bit more familiar in Java, and PHP wasn't configured on my machine. However I did enjoy studying your solution, it has very little overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Finished solution for grabbing image urls;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class Acura {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner read;
    Writer write;
    try {
        File list = new File("F:/result.txt");
        read = new Scanner(list);
        write = new FileWriter("F:/imgurls.txt");
        double s = 0;

        while(read.hasNextLine())
            try {
                s++;
                String url = read.nextLine();
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Element img = doc.select("img").first();
                String imgUrl = img.absUrl("src");
                write.write(imgUrl + "\n");
                System.out.println((double)(s/2690) + "%");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        read.close();
        write.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Generates a nice long list of image urls in a text document.
Could have done it in a non-sequential manner, but was heavily intoxicated when I did this. However I did add a progress bar for my own peace of mind :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner read;
    Writer write;
    try {
        File list = new File("F:/imgurls.txt");
        read = new Scanner(list);
        double s = 0;

        while(read.hasNextLine())
            try {
                s++;
                String url = read.nextLine();
                Response imageResponse = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).execute();
                FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File("F:/Acura/" + (int) s + ".png"));
                writer.write(imageResponse.bodyAsBytes());
                writer.close();
                System.out.println((double)(s/2690) + "%");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        read.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Worked for generating pngs