# Instagram Graph API: Media Thumbnail URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, instagram-api

I'm using the Instagram Graph API in a business account, and almost everything works just fine. I have created a WordPress port of the Facebook SDK, and the function that retrieves the media items looks like this (part of a class, the `$fb` object is already authenticated using the `default_access_token` in the class constructor):

```php
public function get_media( $business_account_id = '', $limit = 15 ) {
    $limit = absint( $limit );

    try {
        $response = $this->fb->get( "/{$business_account_id}?fields=media.limit({$limit}){media_url,caption,thumbnail_url,permalink}" );
        return $response->getDecodedBody();
    } catch ( \Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e ) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    } catch ( \Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e ) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

The fields I'm requesting, as you can see, are: `media_url`, `caption`, **`thumbnail_url`** and `permalink`. The API responds with all the fields except for `thumbnail_url`:

```
array(2) {
    ["media"]=>
    array(2) {
        ["data"]=>
        array(15) {
            [0]=>
            array(4) {
                ["media_url"]=>
                string(91) "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/..."
                ["caption"]=>
                string(356) "[...]"
                ["permalink"]=>
                string(40) "https://www.instagram.com/p/.../"
                ["id"]=>
                string(17) "..."
            }
            ...
        }
        ["paging"]=>
        array(2) {
            ["cursors"]=>
            array(2) {
                ["before"]=>
                string(123) "..."
                ["after"]=>
                string(122) "..."
            }
            ["next"]=>
            string(438) "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/..."
        }
    }
    ["id"]=>
    string(17) "..."
}
```

I get the same response using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), which makes me think is something related to my app, maybe permissions (currently `manage_pages` and `instagram_basic`), a special setting or a bug (I don't think so, but just in case...).

What am I missing?

Comment: can you tel me that how you get business_account_id?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Update 2021

The docs have been updated and the old link doesn't work anymore; here's the new link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media/#fields

The wording has been updated to indicate that the `thumbnail_url` field is only available on `VIDEO` Media.

---

#### Original Answer

Looks like the [`thumbnail_url` is available on video IG Media objects only](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/#metadata). My solution is to process the images with PHP to generate resized versions of the media objects and cache them so I don't have the regenerate them on every request.

Comment: How did you process the images with PHP? I get a 403 when I use PHP to access the images.

Comment: Since my use case is WordPress I used [`media_sideload_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_sideload_image/). If you're working with something else, you can try [saving images from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url) setting up `allow_url_fopen` to `true`.

Comment: Thank you! My use case is WP also.

Comment: This is a solution for the Instagram Basic Display API. Is there a solution for the Instagram Graph API?