# How to get Instagram image resolution for IG media

Tags: api, graph, instagram, media, resolution

Does anyone know how to get images with different resolution using new API Graph
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media

because I only able to get original resolution, and Gmetrix complains it's too big.
or maybe is there a way to resize image somehow.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue.  The old API sends way more metadata about each media item than the graph API does.  I was hoping this would be a straight migration, and didn't realize there would be less data available.  Hoping I'm missing something.

Comment: Found the way to temporary solve this issue:
facebook\instagram gives opportunity to get media content of any post via simple link:
https://instagram.com/p/fA9uwTtkSN/media/?size=t
you able to get t=thumbnais(150*150) m=medium(320*320) l=large(1080*1080 or maybe full size of post) 

More details here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/embedding#response

Comment: This answer explains, how you can resize it with php: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46270724/9620269