# Get file from blob url in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.3

I'm getting the blob URL as 
`blob:http://localhost:3000/a7e2a2d5-6c2d-462c-acbf-171ff64e1e2d`from the frontend.It contains a zip file.I need to download the zip file from that url and store it in the server.
`$request->values['modelfile']` has this blob url.
How can i get the file from that URL in the controller?

Comment: could you provide some relevant data like how you get this URL, how you store your data on db??

Comment: @Sohel0415 yeah sure,i will edit my question now

Comment: can you check  `dd ($_FILES)` if it exists in the file object, from where you get blob? I mean upload ? If its just URL and you want to download then you can use `file_put_contents`

Comment: @GaneshGhalame i'm not getting the file object from the frontend as i mentioned above i'm just getting the blob URL .Please help me out

Comment: and you wanted to store that blob file by downloading from that url correct?

Comment: @Sohel0415 i want to save file in the server and add the image path in the database.so,the question is how to get the file from url

Comment: @GaneshGhalame yes correct

Comment: its really easy check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url

Answer (score 1):

You can download the file from url using :

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://example.com/image.php'); // URL of your blob object
file_put_contents('/my/folder/flower.jpg', $content);
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/724397/1740102

Or

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/image.php');
$fp = fopen('/my/folder/flower.gif', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/724449/1740102

Comment: I tried as you said but it returns an error `file_get_contents(blob:http://localhost:3000/fd147006-83c9-4e0a-8954-491a741e7744): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.When i hit the url in browser ,i'm able to download the file.

Comment: try by removing `blob:` from url

Comment: i tried removing `blob:` also .I got an error say `file_get_contents(http://localhost:3000/0a7131cb-66a7-4a5e-8c35-6a83301af743): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

Comment: Updated the ans try with curl

Comment: i pointed the download path to various folder ,still its throwing an error `fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\smartviewbackend\public): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: If your file exists on same server where you were running your code ?  (local) if yes why you are downloading it, just copy it using `copy('image1.jpg', 'del/image1.jpg');` I am not getting what you trying to do.

Comment: As you suggested i have added the curl code where I have changed from `$fp = fopen('/my/folder/flower.gif', 'wb');` to `$fp = fopen(public_path(), 'wb');`

Comment: you saved my day,so simple, but I guess the bolb should be sent in "data:application/pdf;base64.....",meaning the front end sould use filereader to send this bolb

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
$upload_dir = "upload/";
$img = $_POST['blob_data'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $upload_dir . mktime() . ".png";
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```