# Images not getting download from other drive

Tags: php

How Can I download images to another folder using PHP?

Can anyone help me in downloading the images.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url  check this url.

Comment: Try to ask a question in a better way

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the files in the localhost (xampp\htdocs..) using PHP. Other files in the system can't be accessed.

Answer (score -1):

You can read content of URL using `file_get_contents()` method and then save the data received as image using `file_put_contents()`

```
 $content = file_get_contents('http://www.mysql.com/abc.png');
 file_put_contents('/image/abc.png', $content);
```

Comment: That's good to begin with, adding more informations/explanations is a good way to improve your answer, as it is right now it doesn't deserve this title.