# PHPmailer AddEmbeddedImage from other server image

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmailer

Currently im using phpmailer and using AddEmbeddedImage. This web is using different data source from two server. http://10.99.09.1/ and http://10.99.99.2 this example. SO current my web is hosted under http://10.99.99.2 and all script is run from http://10.99.99.2 mean while when i using phpmailer and try to call the images from server http://10.99.99.1 it doesnt work

```
$imagescontent='http://10.99.09.1/port/upload/file/'.$line["fil_id"].'.png';
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($imagescontent, "my-attach", $imagescontent);
```

but when i try to fetch the images from the same server when the script is hosted its works. Any idea to make this things works where i can fetch the images from other server

Comment: Can you grab the file itself without directly sending it?
If so; you could download the image to a temp dir, then use it's path to send the image as attachment and after sending(success) remove the TMP file.

Comment: what do you mean by grab the file itself without directly sending it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724391/saving-image-from-php-url from this example use the `$img` as attachment.

Comment: nice trick. thanks for the that lovely trick

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this directly. PHPMailer *deliberately* avoids acting as an HTTP client because that's not what it's for, but there are many other functions, packages, and utilities that can help you with that. Most straightforwardly:

```
$imagescontent= file_get_contents('http://10.99.09.1/port/upload/file/'.$line['fil_id'].'.png');
$mail->addStringEmbeddedImage($imagescontent, "my-attach", $line['fil_id'].'.png');
```

Of course there are *many* things that can cause that `file_get_contents` call to fail, and myriad ways that you might want to control how it operates, such as providing authentication, using a proxy, requesting a particular format via an `Accept` header - and that's exactly why PHPMailer doesn't want to be responsible for that - it's an email client, not an HTTP client.